# Select an array of elements in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to wrap up an array of elements into a jQuery object as if they were selected so that I can call various jQuery actions on them.

I'm looking for a function like `foo` below that accepts an array of elements and returns a jQuery object with them in it.

```
var elements = [element1, element2, element3];

$(foo(elements)).click(function() {
    ...
});
```

Can someone shed some light on this?

Thanks much.

Comment: How are you selecting the elements for `elements` in the first place?

Comment: Are the elements in the array existing jQuery wrapped elements or normal DOM references?

Comment: @Daniel I have a table of elements, and I need to select all elements under one column which have the same name format. For example, all form elements that represent a location would have a name in the format foo*.bar*.location, where * is an index. I wasn't sure how to select them, so I was going to do document.getElementById() in a for loop since I know the number of rows.

Comment: @alex They are DOM references.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just do

```
$(elements).click( function(){ ... });
```

if your elements are actual references to the DOM

**demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/dVKEP/

Comment: Note that it processes them in the order in which they appear in the array - which is nice if such a thing is important.

Comment: Like he said, it's only if they are references to the dom. Your fiddle works with jquery selectors.
Kinda makes sense when you think about it. You wouldn't write $($("#id")) to select an element.

Answer (score 4):

Use [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Example:

```
$.each(elements, function(index, element) { 
    $(element).doStuff();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use each to iterate over both objects and arrays

```
var elements = ['element1', 'element1', 'elements3'];
$.each(elements, function(index, value) {
    alert(index + ': ' + value);
});
```

Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/LpZue/